# How to create 2048 random bits from 256 bits?

Tags: random, cryptography, hash-function

Would merely repeating the same value 8 times be sufficient ? Or is there a more clever approach for doing this ? The 256 bit values would be generated from SHA256 of files.

Comment: use it to see a cryptographic random number generator.

Comment: I think this is the best approach yes. I found http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx
 which seems to do something pretty close to that.

Answer (score 2):

Random numbers for cryptography are a tough subject because you need true random numbers and that is a difficult subject!

However, the method you are suggesting is not sufficient whatsoever for cryptographic purposes.

You should have a look at the [*NIST Recommendation for Random Number 
Generation Using Deterministic Random Bit Generators*](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-90A/SP800-90A.pdf).

Also, you might want to have a look at the "Handbook of Applied Cryptography".

Lastly, you might want to learn about [*DIEHARDER*](http://www.phy.duke.edu/~rgb/General/dieharder.php) and [*TESTU01*](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~simardr/testu01/tu01.html) for testing the quality of your random bits as you need high entropy source.

If this is for non-crypto purpose, you might want to use [*Keccak - SHA3*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-3) to extend the number of bits.

Regards

Comment: Thank you so much for your recommendations. I can't use Keccak I think, because there isn't a ready-made Microsoft C# implementation yet. I ended up using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx giving it the SHA256/SHA512 hash, and getting back 256 random bytes (2048 bits).

Comment: This needs more thumbs up! got one from me ;-)

Comment: True RNG is a very tricky business and is a really hard area! Thx